# JS function not returning value properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I am using qz print Api for printing labels.It has its own function (JS) which displays default printer in alert. I want to display printer name in a div. I have achieved till now. My code is below.

```
function useDefaultPrinter() {
var printer; 
if (isLoaded()) {
// Searches for default printer
qz.findPrinter();
window['qzDoneFinding'] = function() {
// Alert the printer name to user
printer = qz.getPrinter();

window['qzDoneFinding'] = null;
defaultFound = true;
};
    }
alert(printer);
return(printer);
}
```

For displaying HTML

```
var printer_name = useDefaultPrinter();
lbDownHtml += "<div><span>Default printer found: '" + printer_name + "'</span>";
lbDownHtml += "</div>";
```

The problem is that if i dont use alert(printer) in useDefaultPrinter() before return it displays undefined, but if the alert is there like above code it displays undefine in alert but perfect output in html where i have print it. What is the issue? as i dont want to alert (but if i dont use it it shows undefined).

Comment: Don't you need to prefix "useDefaultPrinter()" with "qz."? You also have </a> with no anchor element.

Comment: Don't you need to prefix "useDefaultPrinter()" with "qz."? i didnt get u here i have removed </a> that i mistakenly typed

Comment: Try using: var printer_name = qz.useDefaultPrinter();

Comment: @rontornambe I dont need that bec qz has no scope in that view file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know very little about this API, but this is actually a common issue.

The `qz.findPrinter()` function appears to be **asynchronous** - it will still be actively running when your `useDefaultPrinter` function has finished.

For *asynchronous* functions, you cannot simply return the value you want, because it doesn't exist yet. The most common resolution is to add a "callback" argument to your function (`callback` would, itself, be a "function variable"). Then, call that callback function when the object you need is available. In your code, this would be here:

```
// Alert the printer name to user
printer = qz.getPrinter();
```

Once that's in place, you would need to rewrite whatever code outside needs `useDefaultPrinter`.

Before:

```
printer = useDefaultPrinter();
// continue operation here...
```

After:

```
useDefaultPrinter(function(printer) {
  //...continue operation here...
});
```

If you're still confused, search Google for "tutorials on JavaScript asynchronous programming". Based on your username, it seems possible that English is not your first language, so it might be easier to follow if you can find a description that fits your learning style - it tends not to make sense at first for most developers.

Comment: I didnt get u at all please help

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan Tried to edit my post to be a bit clearer. Good luck.